# How to know if a Wiki page is for a person

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

I search a word on Wiki pages using Wiki API. I need to know if that word is a name for a person.

For example searching "Leonardo Dicaprio"

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Leonardo%20Dicaprio&utf8=

I need to know from the query result if this is a name for a person

Comment: This sounds like you are asking how to do something that you should not be doing in the first place, because you have jumped to some premature conclusions about what approach you should take. Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to check if a "Word" is a person's name, so i got the idea of using Wiki articles data, if "Word" is in title of a person article, then "Word" is a person's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better off doing this via the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org) and Sparql.

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel ?article WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?person rdfs:label ?personLabel .
  FILTER( LANG(?personLabel) = "en")
  FILTER( CONTAINS(LCASE(?personLabel), "leonardo dicaprio") ) .
  ?article schema:about ?person .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
}
LIMIT 10
```

(If that times out, you could add more specific searches, e.g. with 'country of citizenship': `?person wdt:P27 wd:Q30`)